# Issue, Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I receive this error when I run my script

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Interaction') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Interaction END;
SELECT   dwf.WavFileKey
        ,di.InteractionKey
        ,dpo.OwnerKey
        ,dwf.ShortInteractionId
        ,fi.InitiatedDateCode
        ,fi.LastLocalUserNameKey
        ,fi.CallDirectionKey
        ,fi.MediaTypeKey
        ,fi.TollFreeKey
        ,fi.WorkGroupKey
        ,fi.IsAnswered
        ,fi.ConnectedDuration
        ,fi.LineDuration
        ,fi.HoldDuration
        ,fi.CallDuration
        ,initated.[Date] AS InitiatedDate
        ,dun.UserName AS LastLocalUserName
INTO #Interaction
FROM Dim.WavFile dwf
INNER JOIN Dim.Interaction di ON di.InteractionId = dwf.InteractionId
LEFT JOIN Fact.Interaction fi ON fi.InteractionKey = di.InteractionKey
LEFT JOIN Dim.[Date] initated ON initated.DateCode = fi.InitiatedDateCode
LEFT JOIN Dim.UserName dun ON dun.UserNameKey = fi.LastLocalUserNameKey
LEFT JOIN Dim.CustomerPrimaryPhone dcp ON dcp.Phone = RIGHT(di.RemoteId,LEN(di.RemoteId)-2)
LEFT JOIN Dim.Owner dpo ON Dpo.OwnerId = dcp.OwnerId
```

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 4, Line 17
> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
> The statement has been terminated.

I tried to change -2 to -100 but changing the LEN didn't work. How can I troubleshoot this or fix the error?

Comment: We can't debug that for you? The error is very clear, so you need to check the values you are passing in for the data you are trying to query. Somewhere your data isn't as you expect. If you want assistance you need to provide a [mre] with sample data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Check the values returned from `LEN(di.RemoteId)` - the error will be thrown when `LEN(di.RemoteId)-2` is less than zero, i.e.: the `RemoteId` values are null or are 0 or 1 characters long.

Comment: Depending on DBMS, nulls won't throw this error. SQL Server for example. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22feee571b879db26e224b6e54a44e2a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`di.RemoteId` has data that is 1 character or less.

You can find them by running

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Dim.Interaction
WHERE LEN(RemoteId) <= 1
```

Comment: there have been other times when this job hasnt failed and the leb of remote id is 1 ,0 or null

Comment: @Joe You need to protect yourself against it in any case. It could be that last time you got a plan where those problematic values were filtered out earlier, and now you're getting a different plan where SQL Server is trying to apply `RIGHT()` _before_ filtering out values that are too short. You can't control that behavior, so don't say `RIGHT(col, LEN(col)-2))` if it's possible for `LEN(col)` to be `< 2`. Use a `CASE` expression to optionally decide what to do when there aren't two characters (or fix the data, which this answer explains how to find, and add a constraint to prevent it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you. sorry for late response. could you please upvote my question if you feel it was a decent/legit question. not sure why ive got negative. please let me know how i can improve